# UIView animates slide in but not slide out using block animation method

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I have a UIView called geopointView. I want to animate slide in  this UIview on main view frame when a button (myButton) is pressed. If myButton is pressed again UIview should slide out of frame. myButton calls following method "optionsCalled"

```
-(void) optionsCalled
{
if (![[self.view subviews] containsObject:geopointView] &&checkForGeopointViewAnimation ==0) {

        [self.view addSubview:geopointView];
        geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(0,430,320,30);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
                         animations:^{
                             geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 350, 100, 80);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             checkForGeopointViewAnimation = 1 ;
                         }];

    }
    if ([[self.view subviews] containsObject:geopointView] && checkForGeopointViewAnimation ==1)
    {

        geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 350, 100, 80);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
                         animations:^{
                             geopointView.frame = CGRectMake(0,430,320,30);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             checkForGeopointViewAnimation = 0 ;
                         }];

        [geopointView removeFromSuperview];

    }

}
```

here checkForGeopointViewAnimation is a global variable defined to ensure slide in and out are not called at one time.

Problem with this code is that UIview slides in animatedly but it does not animate slide out action. it just disappears from main frame. Do I need to use any time here so that there is delay in calling add and remove UIview functions?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `[geopointView removeFromSuperview];` after the completion of the animation

Comment: @amol_subhedar: Please vote up all the answers that helped you just as a token of appreciation.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to call `[geopointView removeFromSuperview];` in your completion block instead?